# How to use elastic search HTTP/REST clients with shield

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch

As we are planning to use shield plugin to provide authentication to elastic search with RESTFUL Clients, we couldn't find any solution to implement.

We can do the same with "CURL" as follows

```
      curl -u es_admin -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/'
```

But how to implement the same with REST Client. do we need set any header properties??. if so,please guide me with proper solution.

Comment: like postman,fiddler ..etc

Comment: Ah, well two things: 1. If you're using Shield, then you should have a license as well as a support contact (where Elastic can answer these questions). 2. Those are just generic tools, so you can _generally_ set the URL to accept the username and password (it's dependent on the tool) using Basic Authentication. For example `http://es_admin:password@localhost:9200/`.